# arduino auto LED on/off signal from python

Tags: python, arduino-uno

The following code is python and it turns my LED on if i type '1' and turns if off if i type '0' this part works:

```
import serial
import time 

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com3',9600) 


while True:        
number = raw_input()

if (number == '1'):
    arduinoData.write('1')

if (number == '0'):
    arduinoData.write('0')
```

Now the following includes randomizing numbers 1 and 0 and hoping for automatic LED on/off... but this next part isn't working!

```
import serial
import time
import random

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com3',9600)     
while True:
    low = 0; high = 1
    ran_number = random.randint(low, high)
    print ran_number
    time.sleep(1)

    if (ran_number == '1'):
        arduinoData.write('1') 
        time.sleep(1)

    if (ran_number == '0'): 
        arduinoData.write('0')
        time.sleep(1)
```

The arduino side code is:

```
int data;
int pin=9;


void setup() { 
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite (pin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
while (Serial.available()){
  data = Serial.read();
}

if (data == '1')
digitalWrite (pin, HIGH);

else if (data == '0')
digitalWrite (pin, LOW);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to sackoverflow. It is hard to understand what is "raw_input' and how you did enter 1 or 0  without the Python code, so please edit your question to be more clear. Also try to fix the code indentation problem. Are you certain that your Arduino is on port "Com3" and uses a speed of 9600 bauds ?

Comment: An important part of any programming is checking - you clearly didn't check your question after submitting it...

Comment: my fault first time, i edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating an `int` value for `ran_number` but then you're comparing it against `str` values. This will surely be `false`. What you should do is to compare `ran_number` with `int` values:

```
import serial
import time
import random

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com3',9600)     
while True:
    low = 0; high = 1
    ran_number = random.randint(low, high)
    print ran_number
    time.sleep(1)

    # please note the int here
    if (ran_number == 1):
        arduinoData.write('1') 
        time.sleep(1)

    # please note the int here
    if (ran_number == 0): 
        arduinoData.write('0')
        print ("LED turned OFF")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @petrpulc thanks for comment! What do you mean by "this not minimal" - that the OP may have also connected to the wrong serial ?

Comment: @Anatolii no, I mean that:
a) instead of checking the random number, it can be directly written to serial port or at least
b) else clause could be used and
c) the `time.sleep(1)` in both branches can be moved out